# Oracle Loop by User Name

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

I found a script that will allow you to End Date a Responsibility by providing the User Name and Responsibility name. I'm trying to figure out how to create this into a loop so that User Name doesn't have to be provided.

Something along the logic of:
if (responsibility exists for user)
  end date
else
  check next user

Here's the script I've been using to end date via user name:

```
DECLARE
v_user_name                   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'PRAJKUMAR';
v_responsibility_name   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'Application Developer';
v_application_name        VARCHAR2 (100) := NULL;
v_responsibility_key        VARCHAR2 (100) := NULL;
v_security_group              VARCHAR2 (100) := NULL;
BEGIN
SELECT  fa.application_short_name,
        fr.responsibility_key,
        frg.security_group_key
INTO    v_application_name,
        v_responsibility_key,
        v_security_group
FROM    fnd_responsibility       fr,
        fnd_application            fa,
        fnd_security_groups  frg,
        fnd_responsibility_tl   frt 
WHERE   fr.application_id               = fa.application_id
AND     fr.data_group_id             = frg.security_group_id
AND     fr.responsibility_id          = frt.responsibility_id
AND     frt.LANGUAGE                 = USERENV ('LANG')
AND     frt.responsibility_name  = v_responsibility_name;

  fnd_user_pkg.delresp
  (    username           => v_user_name,
       resp_app            => v_application_name,
       resp_key             => v_responsibility_key, 
       security_group   => v_security_group 
  );

 COMMIT;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   'Responsiblity '
    || v_responsibility_name
    || ' is removed from the user '
    || v_user_name
    || ' Successfully'
    );
END; 
/
```

Reference: https://blogs.oracle.com/prajkumar/end-date-responsibility-for-oracle-fnd-user

Comment: do you mean just update all records for all users that have some responsibility?

Comment: No; just that specific responsibility. Say the responsibility is "Timecard Approval" but that it's not longer going to be used. I'm trying to loop through all users, check for that responsibility and if it is found, end date it. With the script above, It ends dates "Timecard Approval" for user "12345" but I want it to check all users. Make sense?

Comment: i think you are describing one update statement - not a loop.

Comment: That would be fine. I'm just not sure how to get it to check all users rather than just one specific one. The only thing I could think of was like a counter and loop through users?